# How to extract specific field from JSON array with jq

Tags: arrays, select, jq

I want to process JSON data using jq. Here is an excerpt from the data:

```
{
  "lat": "49.3877286",
  "lon": "6.704062",
  "tag": [
    {
      "k": "name",
      "v": "Beckingen"
    },
    {
      "k": "is_in",
      "v": "Merzig-Wadern,Saarland,Bundesrepublik Deutschland,Europe"
    },
    {
      "k": "place",
      "v": "town"
    },
  ]
}
{
  "lat": "49.287307",
  "lon": "6.8827786",
  "tag": [
    {
      "k": "name",
      "v": "Püttlingen"
    },
    {
      "k": "place",
      "v": "town"
    },
    {
      "k": "population",
      "v": "18748"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to extract the `lat`, `lon`, and `name` fields, like this:

```
{
  "lat": "49.3877286",
  "lon": "6.704062",
  "name": "Beckingen"
},
{
  "lat": "49.287307",
  "lon": "6.8827786",
  "name": "Püttlingen"
}
```

I'm almost there, but I can't figure out how to select a field from an array using `select()`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks,

Enno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your precise requirements, you could use `map(select(...))` or `.[] | select(...)`, along the lines of, for example:

```
.tag[] | select(.k == "name") | .v
```

You might want to make this more robust, for example by taking into account the possibility that there might not be exactly one "name":

```
first(.tag[] | select(.k == "name") | .v // null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it:

```
{lat: .lat, lon: .lon, tag: .tag[]}
| select(.tag.k=="name") 
| {lat: .lat, lon: .lon, name: .tag.v}
```

The trick was to use `.tag[]` which multiplies each entry with the number of array elements in `.tag`, then to select the relevant entries and then to construct the output JSON. Thanks for the hint, @peak!

Comment: You could simplify that to {lat, long, name: (.tag[] | select(.k == "name") | .v)}

Comment: Cool, thanks! For the sake of completion: in this particular case it was `lon`, not `long`.